# scrollToRowAtIndexPath stopped working in iOS 7 - ?UITableViewCellScrollView? Change in UITableViewCell hierarchy

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I upgraded to Xcode 5 and my app to target iOS 7 and my app no longer responded to scrollToIndexPath to scroll the appropiate tableviewcell out of the way of the keyboard

My set up is i had a custom tableview cell, with textfield on it, and was using it to generate multiple tableview cells to display and edit parts of an address.

Tapping on a textfield on a cell triggers

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

And the code to make it scroll to the top , out of the way of the keyboard was as follows

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
[self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

This worked fine in iOS 6 but doesn't work in iOS 7. It also does not generate any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution here is a simple one

It appears that there has been a change in the hierarchy of tableviewCells

So adding an extra .superview

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
```

Becomes

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview.superview;
```

and it works targeting iOS 7.

The textField.superview.superview  used to be an object of class UITableViewCell (or more specifically my custom UITableViewCell)

Now it's an object of class UITableViewCellScrollView and you need to get that its superview.

UITableViewCellScrollView is a private subclass that apparently enables the the slide left to reveal the delete button

[After working this out i found this blogpost which illustrates it nicely](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646)

Hope this stops a few of you pulling your hair out :)

Simon

Comment: What about backwards compatibility?

Comment: For myself i've decided to forget about iOS6 and just target iOS7 - its a new app that hasnt launched yet, however i'm sure a little introspection would reveal which version of iOS is in us and you could  if (){} else{} your way around this

Comment: see the far better solution below as this breaks again under iOS 8. Eric's solution will just keep on working - far more elegent

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer said, the view hierarchy of a UITableViewCell changed in iOS 7.  Instead of using:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
```

Define the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    UIView *view = subview;
    while (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        view = [view superview];
    }
    return view;
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForSubview:textField];
```

This should work in iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: much better than mine - mine would have broken again in iOS8 :)

Comment: which in fact it did !